# Should Bonferroni correction be done on bootstrapped correlations?

Tags: correlation, bootstrap, bonferroni

I have 6 ratio variables. This gives me a total of 15 correlations. I do each one of these correlations with bootstrapping methods, generating 15 confidence intervals, of which 3 are significant because they do not encompass zero. These confidence intervals also come with a t-score. Should I do Bonferroni on these by setting my alpha to .05/15?

Comment: Yes this is still a multiple testing situation, so a correction may be in order. Bonferonni is pretty conservative though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you should do a correction for multiplicity (testing many hypothesis) do not depend on the method used to calculate the p-values, it depends on the nature of the hypothesis tests and your goal. But, as noted in comments, Bonferroni is quite conservative so there might be better methods.

Comment: Since you were brave enough to post an answer so long after, Ill give it to you!